# Select max for each variable combination in data.frame

Tags: r

I am trying to find an easy way to the last paid price for a product-customer combination.

```
customers <-  c("cust_a","cust_b","cust_a","cust_b")
products <- c("prod_a","prod_b","prod_a","prod_b")
dates <- c("2011/10/25","2011/09/14","2011/03/12","2011/05/06")
prices <-c("10","12","15","18")
df <- cbind(customers,products)
df <- cbind(df, dates)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(df,prices))
```

Next I would like to create a new data.frame with for every customer - product combination of the price with the highest date. In this example data.frame the cust_a and prod_1 combination will give 10 and the cust_b and prod_2 will give 12.

I know how to do this in SQL, but in this case a SQL solution is not an option for me.

Comment: The package `sqldf` allows you to use SQL queries on data.frames

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `plyr` package for this type of problem:

```
library(plyr)

dat = data.frame(
  customers =  c("cust_a","cust_b","cust_a","cust_b"),
  products = c("prod_a","prod_b","prod_a","prod_b"),
  dates = c("2011/10/25","2011/09/14","2011/03/12","2011/05/06"),
  prices =c("10","12","15","18")
)
```

First convert the `dates` column to class `Date` using `as.Date`.  This allows easy operation, including finding the maximum:

```
dat$dates <- as.Date(dat$dates)
```

Next, use `ddply`. This splits a `data.frame` into chunks, applies a function to each chunk and then returns a `data.frame` after combining all of the pieces.  The function you want to apply to each chunk is `subset`, specifically that subset where `dates==max(dates)`:

```
ddply(dat, .(customers, products), subset, dates==max(dates))

  customers products      dates prices
1    cust_a   prod_a 2011-10-25     10
2    cust_b   prod_b 2011-09-14     12
```

Comment: @user1053718 Glad to be of help. When you have decided which answer is most helpful, remember to accept it by clicking on the tick-mark symbol.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using the `plyr` package. Here is the solution

```
# CONVERT DATES TO DATE FORMAT
df <- transform(df, dates = as.Date(dates, "%Y/%m/%d"))

# FOR CUSTOMER-PRODUCT COMBINATION, EXTRACT PRICE OF MAX(DATES)
plyr::ddply(df, .(customers, products), summarize, 
  last_price = prices[which.max(dates)])

  customers products last_price
1    cust_a   prod_a         10
2    cust_b   prod_b         12
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `df` is ordered by date (as I can see), than a simple `split` and `lapply` would do the job:

```
lapply(split(df, df$customers), function(x) x$prices[1])
```

If not, than order your `df` before the above line, or implement it in the inner function :)

---

Results:

```
> lapply(split(df, df$customers), function(x) x$prices[1])
$cust_a
[1] 10
Levels: 10 12 15 18

$cust_b
[1] 12
Levels: 10 12 15 18

> sapply(split(df, df$customers), function(x) x$prices[1])
cust_a cust_b 
    10     12 
Levels: 10 12 15 18
```

---

**Update**: the above example was run against only `customers` as in the example `products` has no role. But for combinations use a list as `f` parameter of `split`, eg.:

```
> lapply(split(df, list(df$customers, df$products)), function(x) x$prices[1])
$cust_a.prod_a
[1] 10
Levels: 10 12 15 18

$cust_b.prod_a
[1] <NA>
Levels: 10 12 15 18

$cust_a.prod_b
[1] <NA>
Levels: 10 12 15 18

$cust_b.prod_b
[1] 12
Levels: 10 12 15 18
```